# When I run docker-compose up command, getting this error. Can somebody help me?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[1]Cannot start service be: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused "rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting

[Terminal Screenshot ][2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ25W.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB3sI.png

Comment: Show your docker-compose file.....

Comment: We would need more information than is given here to help you. Update you question with the contents of the dockerfile in question, the docker-compose file, and the directory you are running from (full path in wsl).

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be with volumes mentioned in docker-compose.yml file.